Unmounting an external drive
Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS whenever I connect an external storage device (USB key or SSD in a caddy) via a USB, when I then try to disconnect the drive prior to removing the USB cable (right mouse click, Safely Remove Drive) I get an error message "One or more applications are keeping the drive busy". The options are to cancel the disconnect or eject anyway.
How can I find out what is keeping the drive busy, and is there any risk in selecting the Eject Anyway button?
This has only started happening since the upgrade. Is it a bug? I have also noticed that if I use Nautilus to move or delete a file or folder the file or folder doesn't immediately disappear from its old location, so I'm wondering if the 2 things might be connected.

It seems to be a "feature" of Nautilus in Ubuntu 24.04.1; I upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 and first noticed ZuluCrypt not being able to unmount and have since noticed the same as you with USB flash drives.

The work-around is to either close the Nautilus window showing the USB drive, or just move it to another directory, e.g. Home. To see what is causing a device to be "busy", use something like "lsof /media/username/devicename"
